# Angular5 use external component in Lazy loaded Module

Tags: javascript, angular5, lazy-loading

I has LazyModule which I load lazy, and another one ModuleA. I need to use component Module-A-Component inside LazyModule. How can I access this external component? I use Module-A-Component around all application.

If I add Module-A-Component in daclaration array of LazyModule got the error:

> Module-A-Component is part of the declarations of 2 modules...

If I move Module-A-Component only in LazyModule I can't use it in other parts of application.

How can I use the external component in lazy loaded module and other modules?

Comment: would you mind accepting or rejecting the answer . That would help me improve or remove an unwanted answer from SO

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no code, so I am gonna give a theoretical answer. You need to create a `shared-module`. Create `Module-A-Component` inside it and name it accordingly. Then reuse it in `MOdule A` , `MOdule-B` and so on.

This will also make sure that there are no circular dependecy.